# Reading access database with infile statement

Tags: sas

**TLDR:**

I want to read my access database via infile statement to have complete control over format,informat,length of variables/columns

I have an access database which has around 2 million records.Currently I am importing it with **PROC IMPORT.**

**The problem:**

From what I have read that **PROC IMPORT** uses around 32k rows to set format,informat,length for variables I feel that data may be getting truncated.

Another problem is all my character variables have format and informat as $255.and length as 255.I  dont want my all variables to be of this length,format,informat.

I want some variables to be more than 255 and some to be less than 255.

**My current code:**

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= Input.access_db 
DATATABLE= "DATABASE" 
DBMS=ACCESSCS REPLACE; 
DATABASE="\\Input\Entire_Records.accdb"; 
SCANMEMO=YES; 
USEDATE=YES; 
SCANTIME=NO; 
RUN;
```

I want to do above with an infile statement.

I have a code to import my csv via infile statement.But I am not getting how do I modify it to make it to read my access database

```
data Input.Real;
%let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
infile 'Input\Real.csv'
delimiter = ',' 
MISSOVER 
DSD 
lrecl=32767 
firstobs=2 ;
informat ID 11.;
informat IDENTIFIER $255. ;
informat LINE_CODE $255. ;
informat ACTION $255. ;

format ID 11.;
format IDENTIFIER $255. ;
format LINE_CODE $255. ;
format ACTION $255. ;

input

ID
IDENTIFIER $
LINE_CODE $
ACTION $ ;

if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
RUN;
```

Comment: What makes you think that proc import is not honoring the data types defined by Access?

Comment: Its just I am not sure if there is any truncation is happening or not.I dont want data to be truncated(Since every character variable is set to 255 but I am not sure if that is what the maximum in access database)

Comment: You should open the access file using Access and check the metadata about the variables there.  If SAS is really truncating them at 255 characters then your question for this forum can become "how can I read character variables from Access database files where length is longer than 255 characters".  That should get more precise answers.

Comment: 255 is the maximum length for character fields in Access. For longer text you need use what they used to call Memo fields.  Do your files have memo fields?

Comment: If access database itself cant take more than 255 characters then will there be any record which is more than 255 characters in access ?

Comment: "From what I've read" can you link to the information ? `DBMSCS`  should be examining the metadata of the Access table *DataBase* and constructing SAS columns appropriately similar to the Access ones.  Did you try importing only a small number of rows to see what you get ? If you have, were there any log messages.  If you did, can you describe the variables that are shorter or longer than the source variables in Access ? Is there a reason you are not using a Access engined LIBREF (`libname myacc access '...mydb.accdb';`)